# how can i get change event of today, next and previous button?

Tags: angular, calendar, angular-calendar

I am using `angular-calendar` plugin to display my event in calendar but I want get it's change event it's possible ?

```
<mwl-demo-utils-calendar-header [(view)]="view" [(viewDate)]="viewDate">
    </mwl-demo-utils-calendar-header>
```

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: i am using angular 9 vesrion @QTRay

Comment: Have you used the (eventClicked)="eventHandler($event)"?

Comment: yes i have try but i get full mouse event i want to get date of the calender for e.g if user click on next button get the next month date @QTRay

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="btn btn-outline-secondary" mwlCalendarToday [(viewDate)]="viewDate" (click)="todayClicked()"> Today</div>`

> You can add click event in div tag